# How to use sqlite icu in like query

Tags: c++, sqlite

hi I modified my sql statement as

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE [v_fts] USING fts4 
(
 [title], 
tokenize=icu
)"
```

But when I am trying to insert data I am getting error `SQL logic error or missing database`

**Edit**

I had compiled sqlite with icu option using -`DSQLITE_ENABLE_ICU`

option.

how to load icu ?

I had uploaded shell code with makefile here

http://www.2shared.com/file/8hxA3KIn/sqlite.html

```
all: release32

CFLAGS = -fPIC -O6 -DNO_TCL -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DHAVE_USLEEP=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1  -O3 -Os  -I. -DSQLITE_ENABLE_ICU `/home/vivek/downloads/icu/des32/bin/icu-config --cppflags`

export LDFLAGS += -Wl,--start-group 
export LDFLAGS += /home/vivek/downloads/icu/des32/lib/libsicui18n.a
export LDFLAGS += /home/vivek/downloads/icu/des32/lib/libsicuuc.a
export LDFLAGS += /home/vivek/downloads/icu/des32/lib/libsicudata.a
export LDFLAGS += -lcrypt -ldl -lz -lrt  -lssl -lpthread   
export LDFLAGS += -Wl,--end-group

OBJ=sqlite3.o\
    shell.o\
    icu.o\

release32: $(OBJ)
     g++34  -fno-exceptions -fno-operator-names ${CFLAGS} -DNDEBUG -m32  -static  $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS) -o s.out
%.o:%.c
    gcc34 ${CFLAGS} -DNDEBUG -m32 -c    $<
```

my query are

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE [vivek_fts] USING fts4 ( [title],tokenize=icu en_US)
insert into vivek_fts values("a");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the full text search documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) you should use `tokenize=icu en_US` for example (specify an ICU locale identifier).

Also, you should have ICU loaded.

Comment: you should have ICU loaded.
sorry I didn't get that ?
how to do that ?

Comment: I added the step I followed to compile sqlite with icu. Now how to load icu in sqlite inside program ? I am using icu extension from sqlite.

Comment: if libicu is available and can be loaded by SQLite, it should then work.

Comment: I had added full code zip file with my make file can you please check check once.